# Jagged canvas rendering in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm writing a drawing application using HTML canvas. To smooth drawn lines, I'm filling a series of quadratic curves after each `mousemove` event:

```
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(mx1-halfLastWidth*sin(angle), my1-halfLastWidth*cos(angle))
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(mx1-lastWidth*cos(angle), my1+lastWidth*sin(angle),
      mx1+halfLastWidth*sin(angle), my1+halfLastWidth*cos(angle))
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(xl+halfMidWidth*sin(angle), yl+halfMidWidth*cos(angle),
      mx2+halfCurrentWidth*sin(angle), my2+halfCurrentWidth*cos(angle))
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(mx2+currentWidth*cos(angle), my2-currentWidth*sin(angle),
      mx2-halfCurrentWidth*sin(angle), my2-halfCurrentWidth*cos(angle))
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(xl-halfMidWidth*sin(angle), yl-halfMidWidth*cos(angle),
      mx1-halfLastWidth*sin(angle), my1-halfLastWidth*cos(angle))
    ctx.fill()
```

Full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PfzM2/2/ (there's a lot of irrelevant code due to this being extracted from a much larger project)

The lines render very smoothly in Firefox, but seem "jagged" in places in Chrome:

[image]

The series of commands and arguments issued to the browsers was identical.

How can I get Chrome to render the lines like Firefox?

Comment: Post a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can test it out.

Comment: OK, posted to http://jsfiddle.net/PfzM2/2/

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/hN3Hx.png. (I'm running Chrome 21 on 64-bit Linux)

Comment: Interesting, it may be a platform-specific issue. My original test was with Chrome 21 on OS X. On Windows it seems a little better, but still shows up for slow strokes: http://i.imgur.com/WLESE.png

Comment: For *really* slow strokes I do get some jagged edges, but that seems to be consistent with Firefox's rendering as well: http://i.imgur.com/8d2fs.png. It probably is platform-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions have been asked all over the place with respect to font rendering. It's <strike>almost certainly</strike> possibly the same root problem: anti-aliasing differences that arise from the  rendering engine. Chrome, as you know, uses Webkit; FF, Gecko. Gecko seems to like anti-aliasing more than Webkit.

Chalk it up to a browser issue (the way you would typically would for IE, I reckon).

EDIT: Seems the converse is known to be true, too. Nick Heer discusses this in [his blog](http://nickheer.com/blog/layout/): "due to Gecko’s more precise (and blockier) anti-aliasing, most serif faces don’t look great." Could be a platform issue.